# How to sort multiple column with a column including date?

Tags: linux, command-line, sort

I am trying to sort a file as following which has multiple columns, separated with comma, and one of the column has date with the following format mm/dd/yyyy.

> $cat filename
>
> AN1143,45.7,03/05/2012,
> H9477,45.3,01/15/2010,
> DN1222,45.1,03/05/1800,
> J960,26.7,06/02,1990,
> Z959,28.2,03/21/2016,
> H12421,27.7,06/21/2000

My intention is to sort first based on the first column and then the third column which has the date. I tried the following command:

```
sort -t"," -k1,1 -k3,9n.3,10n -k3,1n.3,2n -k3,4n.3,5n filename
```

but I faced this error any help with explanation is appreciated.

> sort: stray character in field spec: invalid field specification â3,9n.3,10nâ

Comment: can you edit the question and add the result you seek after ?

Comment: `-k3,9n.3,10n` looks to have the comma and period (dot, full stop) characters interchanged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
sort -t, -k1,1 -k3.7n -k3.1,3.2n -k3.4,3.5n < filename
```

- There's no need to quote the comma delimiter
- The first sort-key definition uses column 1
- The second sort-key definition uses column 3's "year" field, sorted numerically
- The third sort-key uses column 3's "month" field, sorted numerically
- The fourth sort-key uses column 3's "day" field, sorted numerically

Sample run with an enhanced sample data file, showing the sorting:

Input:

```
AN1143,45.7,03/05/2012,
AN1143,45.7,02/05/2012,
AN1143,45.7,03/04/2012,
AN1143,45.7,03/05/2011,
H9477,45.3,01/15/2010,
DN1222,45.1,03/05/1800,
J960,26.7,06/02,1990,
Z959,28.2,03/21/2016,
H12421,27.7,06/21/2000
```

Output:

```
AN1143,45.7,03/05/2011,
AN1143,45.7,02/05/2012,
AN1143,45.7,03/04/2012,
AN1143,45.7,03/05/2012,
DN1222,45.1,03/05/1800,
H12421,27.7,06/21/2000
H9477,45.3,01/15/2010,
J960,26.7,06/02,1990,
Z959,28.2,03/21/2016,
```

Comment: in GNU sort, add the `--debug` flag to see the sorting decisions (lines top to bottom indicate the key that was used and in what order)

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeff. what about if I want to keep the same sorting but have the earliest date first and the latest date after (like reverse of the current date sorting )?

Comment: I'm confused by "keep the same sorting" and "change the current sorting" :)  it's already 'earliest date first', *after* sorting on column 1...

Comment: I'm dubious about the advice not to quote the delimiter in this case.  Doing so does no harm, and is arguably a good general rule.  If you _always_ do so, you don't have to worry (or think) about whether you _need_ to in each case you come across.

Comment: Sorry Jeff, My Bad! :'D. I mean how in general I can reverse the current date sorting based on your code. (i.e. latest first and the earliest)?

Comment: @Daniel just append an `r` to the column-3 sort-keys; for example, `-k3.7nr`

Comment: @DopeGhoti Certainly not harmful, I agree. I suppose I like to keep it fresh in my head what's happening, so it's a proactive decision to know that a comma is not special to the shell, and so is passed directly to `sort`. For me, it's also a shorter mental path, as I have to look at `","` longer to decide that the double-quotes get stripped by the shell (and for - what? no - actual reason), to then see that `sort -t` only gets the comma.

Comment: Different brains work differently, and many solutions all work, which is what I love about POSIX (:

Comment: @JeffSchaller Good solution. Thanks for correct advice about double quotes. No one else mentioned this in other solutions I've read. Bullet points explained what each parameter does perfectly and I learned a few more things about sort by reading it.